# How to change variables in a matrix in python for an imported .csv matrix?

Tags: python, maple

I'm importing an .csv file (exported from maple) in python with a matrix (10 by 10) with variables in each element. For example: a*b-c is in (0,0). How can I define a,b and c such that these values are passed to the matrix?

I already tried a = 1, b =2 etc. before I import the .csv matrix but this doesn't work.

```
import numpy as np
my_matrix = np.genfromtxt('MyMatrix.csv', dtype='unicode', delimiter=',')
```

I expect the variables to be passed to the matrix and the matrix to be of type float to be able to take the inverse of it.

Comment: Can you provide the csv file content if it is not too big?

Comment: Is this helpful:
1/4*((-mH-mHB),1/4*(-(p3xi+p4xi)),1/4*(-(p3xi+p4xi)),0,1/4*(-(p3xi+p4xi)),0,0,0,0,0
1/4*((-mH-mHB),1/4*(mH+mHB+mHS)*p3xi^2,1/4*(mH+mHB+mHS)*p3xi^2,1/4*(mH+mHB+mHS)*p3xi^2,1/4*(mH+mHB+mHS)*p3xi^2,0,0,0,0,0
1/4*((-mH-mHB),1/4*(mH+mHB+mHS)*p3xi^3,1/4*(mH+mHB+mHS)*p3xi^3,1/4*(mH+mHB+mHS)*p3xi^3,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,1/4*(mH+mHB+mHS)*p3xi^4,1/4*(mH+mHB+mHS)*p3xi^4,1/4*(mH+mHB+mHS)*p3xi^4,0,0,0,0,0,0
1/4*((-mH-mHB),1/4*(mH+mHB+mHS)*p3xi^5,0,0,1/4*(mH+mHB+mHS)*p3xi^5,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1

Comment: Yes, this is helpful. There are some missing parenthesis in your example, it needs to be fixed to be evaluated. I've put an solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since every equation is in text format, you can evaluate them as Python expressions:

```
import numpy as np
my_matrix = np.genfromtxt('MyMatrix.csv', dtype='unicode', delimiter=',')

a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
my_matrix_eval = np.vectorize(lambda x: np.float64(eval(x)))(my_matrix)
```

Note: This will solve the problem as asked in the question. However, since the example you provided in the comments contains an operator (`^`) that is not a valid Python expression, these characters will have to be converted to its corresponding Python operator (`**`).

Comment: Thank you very much! Problem solved. For the operator problem I did the following: new_data = np_f.replace(my_matrix, '^', '**')